# Stack Overflow error with Vectors

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, stack-overflow, opencv3.0

I have the following code which causes stack overflow. I don't know why. None of the values I used is out of boundaries when exception occurs. It is called as this Contour_Depth_Search(0, tmp, 0); where tmp=0;

```
// Global Variables
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
vector<vector<Point>> approx_corners, contours;
vector<Point> temp_corner, fiducial_centers;`enter code here`
vector<vector<int>> index_value;
vector<vector<int>> index_depth;

void Contour_Depth_Search(int Indice, int &Nb_Solutions, int depth_level) { 
// Check if current contour is part of a solution
if (approx_corners[Indice].size() == 4) {
    if (!index_depth[Nb_Solutions].empty() && index_depth[Nb_Solutions].back() == depth_level) {
        index_value[Nb_Solutions][index_value[Nb_Solutions].size() - 1] = Indice;
        //index_depth[Nb_Solutions][index_depth[Nb_Solutions].size() - 1] = depth_level;
    }
    else {
        index_value[Nb_Solutions].push_back(Indice);
        index_depth[Nb_Solutions].push_back(depth_level);
    }
}

// I can only search for deeper tree if I found a square in current level or no solutions is started yet (deeper_allowed)
if (hierarchy[Indice][2] != -1) {
    Contour_Depth_Search(hierarchy[Indice][2], Nb_Solutions, depth_level+1);}

// I only go to next node if I cannot find a square in current contour
if (hierarchy[Indice][0] != -1) {
    Contour_Depth_Search(hierarchy[Indice][0], Nb_Solutions, depth_level);}

if (index_value[Nb_Solutions].size() >= 8) {
    Nb_Solutions++;
    index_value.push_back(vector<int>());
    index_depth.push_back(vector<int>());
}
else if (!index_value[Nb_Solutions].empty() && index_depth[Nb_Solutions].back() == depth_level) {
    index_value[Nb_Solutions].pop_back();
    index_depth[Nb_Solutions].pop_back();
}
return;
}
```

Comment: afaik stack overflow is not caused by out of bounds, but by too large objects placed on the stack. How big are those vectors?

Comment: btw when you are in doubt about out of bounds you can use `.at()` instead of `[]` to make sure.

Comment: They are about 4000 elements each. All vectors have same size.

Comment: All variables are cleared prior to calling the function, so no overgrowing variables either.

Comment: How deep is the recursion? Maybe your program just went too far down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Worst case scenario is all elements are child of each other and recursion may go about 4000 times (Not seen so far). On average, it is about 100 element or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution via assigning my Stack:reserve as 2000000. I don't know why with 3000 elements I hit stack overflow, but w/o changing my code, there is no quick solution.

Comment: You'd better correct your wrong designed recursion, instead of relying on dirty tricks which may be fooled by other input data.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stack grows downward in-memory, the size of the stack must be pre-defined. Stack overflow exceptions occur when *stackPointer < topOfStack*, meaning too much data was put on the stack.

In the case of your code, you seem to be using recursion (Contour_Depth_Search calls itself). When a function is called, information is passed around on the stack. As a result, stack overflows are a typical symptoms of unbound recursion. I suspect that is your issue. Without any of the input data it's not really possible for me to help you further, but you can debug it yourself to determine why it is recursing so deeply.

Comment: My code basically searches for a pattern recursively via looking hierarchy tree I acquired. As a result, it needs to search the whole tree recursively. I know the worst scenario but I don't know how to prevent stack overflow error.

Comment: Unless the data you're getting is extremely large, I don't think you'll hit a stack overflow naturally. There's typically at least 1MB of room on the stack. You're passing 12 bytes, plus a return address, plus room for stack frame, meaning around 20 bytes per function call. That's nearly 50,000 recursions before you overflow the stack. If you need to work with data that large, change your compiler options to allow more room on the stack or (better) re-write the code to not use recursion.

Comment: I watched my data and I hit stack overflow after calling my funciton with 3541 of indice. (All previous calls are recursive). Total size of vectors are 3620 and same for all vectors.

Comment: Check your compiler options, you should be able to increase your stack size.